# How to display days in rows using fullcalender.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Below is the link for a calender in which I am showing different days in columns.I just want to display the this days in rows instead of columns.Please help.

[image: Calender link]

Comment: You have to improve the way you ask at StackOverflow: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: have you tried this Datepicker :[Jquery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Maybe listview will work for you. You can check fullcalendar listview - https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/demos/list-views.html